# "%e%" and "%v%" use in R

Tags: r

I've run across some example R code (using the statnet and network packages) that contains a few notations i'm not familiar with...not unusual as i'm a VERY casual R user.

I'm wondering specifically about "%v% and "%e%".

Examples:

`item.statnet%v%"foo"=log(item.codegree)`
`plot.network(item.statnet,edge.col="gray",edge.lwd=item.statnet%e%"edge.lwd",label="vertex.names")`

I've tried some searches but strings like "R" and "%e%" don't work well with google, apparently.....

Comment: You should be able to find the help page in R with `?"%e%"`. Those seem to be specifically from the `network` package and also are on the help page for `?network.extraction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%v%` is a vertex attribute operator:

It can be used in place of `get.vertex.value()` to retrieve the values for the vertices of a network or it can be used in place of `set.vertex.value()` to set values for vertices.

`%e%` is an edge attribute operator:

It can be used in place of `get.edge.value()` to retrieve the values for the outer edges of a network or it can be used in place of `set.edge.value()` to set values for extant (pre-existing) edges.

Answer (score 0):

Took `??"%e%"` but wouldn't have gotten there without your `?"%e%"` suggestion so thank you!